# Is it possible to read a cookie from a different sub-domain? If so, how?

Tags: cookies

I'm currently doing development on a site for a client. This site will be hosted on a subdomain of the client's main site. The client's main site is

`www.xyz.com`

and the site I'm working on will be hosted at

`funds.xyz.com`

Anyone who visits www.xyz.com will have a cookie written to their machine which contains data specifying the user's region. I need that data on my site. Is it possible for me to get access to this cookie?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, so long as the cookie is set for domain ".xyz.com" (note the leading "."). This makes the cookie available to all subdomains of xyz.com

On the other hand, if the domain is "www.xyz.com", the cookie is only visible to the www subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you create a cookie with domain name: .xyz.com it will be accessible across all sub domains.